# Unable to save the translate page node

Tags: translation, drupal-9, contentmode

I have enabled the Content Moderation Module for all the content types. Unable to save the translated content, when editing the existing translated content. And getting this below message.

> Fields applicable to all languages ​​are hidden to avoid conflicts with changes.

Can you please guide me?